# How can a workflow update a field based on another field on separate page layout?

Tags: workflow, formula, lookup, picklist

I have two page layouts. One is for Customers, the other is for Partners.

I have two Partner Fee fields. One is on the Customer page layout, the other is on the Partner page layout. They are both picklists.

These two layouts are connected by a lookup field, "Partner", which is on the Customer layout.

I need the value inside the Partner Fee Field on the Customer layout to  match that of the Partner Fee Field on the Partner layout, but I also need it to be editable. So if I chose to make the Partner Fee 10% for a Partner (let's call this partner, "Test"), the Customer that "Test"  is connected to via lookup field should then have a Partner Fee of 10%, too. But I could change it to 40%, if I wanted to.

To achieve this, I've tried a process builder with multiple field update flows and several workflow rules (as there more is than just one value inside the picklist field, Partner Fee). But it's not working; I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Can I even do this in a workflow or process builder?

My workflow rule criteria is:

ISPICKVAL( Partner__r.Partner_Fee__c, "10%")

My workflow action is a field update, that updates the Partner Fee field on the Customer layout to read "10%" too.

So my question is, can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So...you have a `Customer__c` object which looks up to the `Partner__c` object?

Comment: You may wish to simply use a formula on `Customer` that is `TEXT(Partner__r.Partner_Fee__c)`.

Comment: @adrian larson, They're two separate page layouts of the same object, Account, if that makes sense. A formula would be easier, but I want to be able to edit the field too.

Comment: Sure, I think you mean `RecordType` as well? Anyway, `Partner__c` is a lookup from `Account` to `Account`?

Comment: @adrian Larson, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you have a few options here. My *first choice* would be a formula. Make it `Text` type and then just use:

```
TEXT(Partner__r.Partner_Fee__c)
```

---

If you decide formulas aren't right for you and prefer to go the `Workflow Rule` route, that is still the formula you would need to use in a `Workflow Field Update` as well. In such case, your criteria there should simply be:

```
OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Partner__c))
```

You will need to implement `Process Builder` to sync the value back down to the child `Customer__c` records when `Partner_Fee__c` changes on the `Partner__c` record. There are many steps involved here, but the ones that may be tripping you up are:

- Criteria

  - You should update the child records whenever `Partner_Fee__c` changes.
- Action

  - You should `Update Records` and select the child relationship.
  - Select the `Field` you want to update and use update `Type` of `Formula`
  - The formula should simply read `TEXT([Account].Partner_Fee__c)`

Comment: "The formula should simply read [Account].Partner_Fee__c"  I'm having trouble with this: 'The formula expression is invalid: Field Account is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions' :/

Comment: @ESil Wrap it in `TEXT`, then. `TEXT([Account].Partner_Fee__c`.